# Postfix: selecting relay host based on From: mail header rather than envelope sender

Tags: email, postfix, smtp-headers

I've successfully set Postfix to relay emails via Mandrill using SASL and `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` with a MySQL table so that different senders connect to Mandrill using their own Mandrill username and API key.

So far so good, but I've got three users that all use an Email Service Provider and the Sender in the message envelope is set to "mailer@infusionmail.com" for all three users, and the only place containing the actual user's email address is in the **From: email header**.

I'm happy with the security (or lack thereof) of using the **From: email header** as I'm only forwarding mails sent to specific email addresses that are tightly controlled, but I'd be really grateful for suggestions as to how I can best specify the relayhost based on the value of the **From: header**. Is there any way to set the envelope value to be the same as the From field? Or any other way to do this?

Comment: Did the three user use the same SASL credential?

Comment: No, they each have a different SASL credential. When they're mailing direct from their mailing client, it correctly identifies their mail relay and SASL credentials based on their sending address.  The use of the infusionmail.com ESP is making it impossible at this stage to perform the same lookup based on sender, as the sender is the same and it's only the From: email header that's different.

Answer (score 6):

Based on this thread on postfix mailing-list: [different transport for all mail introduced via sendmail(1)](http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=141096936305892&w=2), looks like your case was possible. Unfortunately you can't only rely on two tables `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` and `smtp_sasl_password_maps`. You need modify `master.cf`. The idea is using `header_checks` to route email to different transport. Then in each transport, we define smtp client that use independent credential and relayhost.

First define header_checks in main.cf and its pcre table

```
#main.cf
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_dependent_relay

#/etc/postfix/header_dependent_relay

/^From:.*specialsender1\@example\.com/       smtp1:[host1.example.com]
/^From:.*specialsender2\@example\.com/       smtp2:[host2.example.com]
/^From:.*specialsender3\@example\.com/       smtp3:[host3.example.com]
```

Good, now we setup `smtp1`,`smtp2`,`smtp3` transport in master.cf

```
#master.cf
smtp1    unix  -       -       -       -       10       smtp
    -o smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/smtp1.relay
smtp2    unix  -       -       -       -       10       smtp
    -o smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/smtp2.relay
smtp3    unix  -       -       -       -       10       smtp
    -o smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/smtp3.relay
```

File `smtpX.relay` has similar content e.g.

```
[hostX.example.com]   userX:passwordX
```

Disclaimer:

- The hash table of `smtp_sasl_password_maps` is only for example. You can replace it with mysql table.
- You can also replace pcre table of header_checks with combination of SELECT and REGEXP in MySQL . But [it may kill your database as postfix will hit MySQL for **every header line**](http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/postfix/2000-07/0849.html)

Comment: See @Aurel's answer too - `FILTER` seems to now be a necessary addition since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with one change: the action "FILTER" needs to be added in the *header_dependent_relay* file:

```
#/etc/postfix/header_dependent_relay

/^From:.*specialsender1\@example\.com/       FILTER smtp1:[host1.example.com]
/^From:.*specialsender2\@example\.com/       FILTER smtp2:[host2.example.com]
/^From:.*specialsender3\@example\.com/       FILTER smtp3:[host3.example.com]
```

See http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

Comment: Same. Without `FILTER` in there, I only got `warning: unknown command in header_checks map: xxx:[xxx.xxx.xxx]`, and obviously, incorrect credentials on the relay attempt.